# Regexp and String manipulation in BASH

Tags: string, bash, brace-expansion

How can I rewrite this command:

```
ls access-19{01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}*.log
```

which is working.

To a form like this:

```
ls access-19{$(seq -ws',' 01 12)}*.log
```

which is not working.

Comment: That's not a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With brace expansion:

```
ls access-19{01..12}*.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In shell, brace expansion is performed before variable expansion so you cannot use variables or command substitution inside `{...}`.

Without using `seq`, you can just use:

```
ls access-19{0{1..9},1{0..2}}*.log
```

Comment: There is a way to put variables inside brace expansion?

Comment: I found a way using: eval ls access-19{$(seq -ws',' 01 12)}*.log

Answer (score 0):

This will works to:

```
eval ls access-19{$(seq -ws',' 01 12)}*.log
```